# How can I find irreducible polynomials in $Z_{77}[x]$?

Tags: polynomials, factoring, unique-factorization-domains

I could find all reducible polynomials in $Z_3[x]$.  But $3$ is a very small number.  I'm interested in finding irreducible polynomials in not very small $N=pq$, where $p,q$ are primes.  I don't have to find all irreducible polynomials.  If I could have a method to just get a few of them, that'd be great.  For instance, say $N = 77$.  How could I get some irreducible polynomials in $Z_{77}[x]$?  That seems awfully daunting.  If fixing a degree helps, that's quite fine.  (Do prefer small degrees.)

Comment: Honestly, this question is very difficult. Computers does it, and there are no specific technics. As far as I know, to check that a polynomial $p(x)$ is irreducible or not in any $\mathbb Z_{k}[X]$ ring, there are no other technics than to test manually if a polynomial of smaller degree divide $p(x)$ or not...

Comment: Alas, that's not what I'd like to hear... But your opinion is good information.  What if I consider a single polynomial $p(x) \in Z_{77}[x]$.  Any method I can provide it is irreducible?

Comment: Just for a story : I asked once to my Galois group teacher if a polynomial was irreducible or not in a specific finite field. His first question was : Where did you find this polynomial ? I answered : it was in one of your exercise sheet. His answer was : at least, we know that we can make it by hand :-).

Comment: And how do you make it by hand?! :-)

Comment: I can do it if the polynomial has degree at most 3 (and if the order of the field is small enough). After, I'm victime to trust computers :-)

Comment: How to get irreducible polynomials in a particular ring using computers?  All I'm interested in is getting some irreducible polynomials to play with but I want to be sure they are indeed irreducible and I know of no way of doing that.